# Spring 4 Web sockets - Do i must have a stomp broker?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

Iv'e been using the following link in order to play with the new spring 4 websockets:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

I was wondering if i must use a stomp broker in order to use the spring framework ? is there any broker less way to use it?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

This guide is using the [simple broker implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/broker/SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.html) provided in Spring Framework. It's just a piece of Java code that plays that part - there's no actual broker in that setup. So yes, there is a broker-less way to use this, and you're already doing it.

This implementation lacks many features though, and you may want to use a real broker (like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)) in production.

**Edit:**

You don't *have to* use STOMP and a message broker, in fact you can use the [Websocket API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-server) directly. As stated in [this presentation](https://rstoyanchev.github.io/nycjava-meetup-2014/#31):

> Using a WebSocket API directly is a bit like writing a custom Servlet
>   application, except the WebSocket protocol is on lower level than HTTP.

Depending on your app goals, you may go towards a message-driven application anyway; not an easy task to solve on your own...

Comment: Yes, I know, but is it possible to use the websocket with spring without ANY stomp broker? or Stomp is mandatory when you choose to use spring with websockets?

Comment: @Urbanleg no its not mandatory its optional if you want to use stomp or not. Stomp is a higher level protocol so you don't need to deal with low level session handling stuff for websocket.

Comment: But what if I want to use stomp but don't provide a message broker? I would like to provide interface to handle stomp event myself instead of relying on the message broker

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using STOMP as it requires a framework to be embedded in your code. Frameworks come and go, and need to be updated.

You can use a Spring (boot) WebSocket channel to pass JSON without ever using STOMP. If you are talking with a front end application (e.g. JavaScript) the JSON is already your "model" data that can easily be passed/parsed bidirectionally.

The WebSocket API contains enough to be able to onConnect(), onMessage(), onError() your implementation. Actually I prefer this, because I am in control. For instance in the onConnect, you can validate tokens and customize security.